# Angular 17 Interceptor Causing Infinite Loop Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, interceptor, angular17

I have created an Angular 17 app and added an interceptor to handle errors and add tokens. However, I am facing an issue with the interceptor causing an infinite loop. Below is the code for my interceptor:

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { LoaderService } from '../Services/loader/loader.service';
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';

export const httpInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandlerFn) => {
 const router = inject(Router);
 const loader = inject(LoaderService);

 // Token check
 const token = (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') ? localStorage.getItem('authToken') : false;

 if (token && !req.url.includes('auth/register') && !req.url.includes('auth/login/') && !req.url.includes('auth/token/')) {
   // Clone the request and add Authorization header
   req = req.clone({
     setHeaders: {
       Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
     }
   });
 } else if (token) {
   let decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
   const isExpired = decodedToken && decodedToken.exp ? decodedToken.exp < Date.now() / 1000 : false;

   if (isExpired) {
     // Token is expired, navigate to login
     localStorage.removeItem('authToken');
     router.navigateByUrl('/signin');
     return throwError(() => 'Token expired');
   }
 } else {
   // Handle the case when there is no token if needed
 }

 // Loading indicator
 loader.setLoading(true, req.url);

 // HTTP requests
 return next(req).pipe(
   tap(event => {
     if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
       loader.setLoading(false, req.url);
     }
   }),
   catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    
       if ([401, 403].includes(error.status)) {
         // Unauthorized or forbidden, navigate to login
         localStorage.removeItem('authToken');
         router.navigateByUrl('/signin');
       }
    
     loader.setLoading(false, req.url);
     return throwError(() => error);
   })
 );
};
```

And here is the code for the home component making the API request:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LibraryService } from '../../Services/courses/library.service';
import { CourseCardComponent } from '../../Core/course-card/course-card.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,CourseCardComponent],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home.component.scss'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit  {
  courses=[];
  constructor(private libraryService:LibraryService)
  {
    
  }
  
  ngOnInit(){
   this.getCourses();
  }
  getCourses(){
    this.libraryService.getCourses().subscribe({
          next:(res)=>{
            console.log("res:",res);
            this.courses=res;
    
            console.log("courses:",this.courses);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

app.config.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch, withInterceptors} from '@angular/common/http';
import { httpInterceptor } from './Interceptors/http.interceptor';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch(),withInterceptors([httpInterceptor])), provideAnimations() 
  ]
};
```

LoaderService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {

  loadingSub: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
 
  loadingMap: Map<string, boolean> = new Map<string, boolean>();

  constructor() { }
  
  setLoading(loading: boolean, url: string): void {
    if (!url) {
      throw new Error('The request URL must be provided to the LoadingService.setLoading function');
    }
    if (loading === true) {
      this.loadingMap.set(url, loading);
      this.loadingSub.next(true);
    }else if (loading === false && this.loadingMap.has(url)) {
      this.loadingMap.delete(url);
    }
    if (this.loadingMap.size === 0) {
      this.loadingSub.next(false);
    }
  }

}
```

I would appreciate any guidance on resolving the infinite loop issue caused by the interceptor. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add LoaderService setLoading() method. Is it a http call service ?

Comment: You need place the debugger in the `interceptor` code check the stack trace, mostly signup is calling some API on load which might be the cause, if youre not able to solve it, please provide a minimal reproducible example with the issue happening and share in the question for debugging!